# Building r packages

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I have recently built and R package for my online course. However, when I run travis-ci build, it grounds to a halt due to the following error:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gert’

* removing ‘/home/travis/R/Library/gert’

Error in i.p(...) : 

  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘gert’ had non-zero exit status

Calls: <Anonymous> ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p

Execution halted

The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

I would appreciate it if you could give me some hints on how to pass this test.
I also run R cmd check on my package and the only warning I receive is the following:

```
WARNING
  'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
```

However, this check in also halted.

Comment: It might be a good idea to share what your warnings are.

Comment: Aside from the warnings, please edit your question to include relevant code here, rather than a link to an external site (the question needs to be self-contained).

Comment: Thank you very much, the above warnings have been solved, there only remains the one I got for knitr version:

Given my rstudio version is 4.0.2 : ``` Found the following significant warnings: Warning: package 'knitr' was built under R version 4.0.3 , Do you think I have to update my rstudio to get past this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `\code{\link[dplyr:filter]}` should be `\code{\link[dplyr]{filter}}`, see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Cross_002dreferences . That should (?) solve some of your problems, don't know if it will solve all of them.

Comment: It did! thank you very much indeed. I don't receive any more of those warnings I mentioned above.  There is another warning which I thought may not be important, I would appreciate it if you had any ideas about them:
```
> checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
   WARNING
  'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about that qpdf one

Comment: correction: you only need to worry about qpdf if (1) you plan to submit to CRAN and (2) you have Rnw-based vignettes whose compiled form is large enough for CRAN to complain about them

Comment: Thank you very much! I also get the following error regarding knitr version, given my rstudio version is 4.0.2 :
```
Found the following significant warnings:
     Warning: package 'knitr' was built under R version 4.0.3
```
Do you think I have to update my rstudio to get past this one?

Comment: That last one should be truly harmless (I'm 99% sure)

Comment: The problem is I can't pass travis-ci check. For that reason I suspected this warning. Thank you very much for your time.